# Вопрос про двойное (подряд) отрицание

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос, наверное, глупый, но ответа не могу найти.

Собственно, в предложении "Значит, он не не был против освободить вас под залог, когда у вас были проблемы с Комиссией по ценным бумагам?" правильно использовано двойное "не", или так нельзя?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Хотел тоже поправить падеж, но не решился. Выходит, можно смело править в подобном случае с отрицанием, когда речь не о конкретном предмете?

Comment: Тём, может я непотихоньку обнаглеваю? Знаешь правило - правь взад. Тут может быть важен порядок слов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Значит, он не не был против освободить вас под залог...**

Думаю, что эта конструкция практически не применяется, кроме особых случаев, например:

Он не был и не не был ― являлся, казался, был предполагаем. [Б. Ю. Поплавский. Аполлон Безобразов (1932)]

Я даже это… не это… не, не был, да… [М. А. Булгаков. Бубновая история (1926)]

**Двойным отрицанием** обычно называют отрицание с модальным глаголом: не мог не прийти, поэтому пришел.

В приведенном примере лучше сделать замену (пример исправлен):

Значит, **он не хотел освободить** вас под залог, когда у вас были проблемы с Комиссией по ценным бумагам.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что он возражал! "Был против" Вы заменили на возражал, а "не" просто убрали, в итоге смысл изменился на противоположный.

Answer (score 1):

Так нельзя (с двумя подряд частицами), разве что в разговоре такая небрежность случается. Можно так:

> Значит, не было такого, чтобы он был не против освободить...